# Why is the moving average called that way?

Tags: time-series, auto-correlation, moving-average

I am a beginner in time-series analysis.

The moving average model uses past errors*parameter, so why is it called a moving average model?

It seems counter-intuitive to me. The Auto-Regressive model seems closer to moving average to me as it uses previous values.

Comment: Welcome to SE. These questions are best for stats.SE (and asked before there). https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/58242/322254

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more about statistics than finance and, importantly, has been asked and answered on Cross Validated.